# How to draw container outside screen width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create a container with rounded corners as shown below?
I tried using container with width more than the screen width. But that constraints it inside the screen. I tried using an OverFlow box, but couldn't get the same result as well. I don't want to use clipRect to make this as I want to apply animation on the corners.

[image: required]

**Edit: Added container snippet with the resulting outcome to clear doubts**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  body: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
      height: 500,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Have you tried having a container with a `BoxDecoration` which `shape` property is a circle?

Comment: i can't understand you clearly

Comment: Hi. Could you please give a little more detail? Why would you want a container larger than the screen size ? Since its useless and won’t be viewed anyways.

Comment: Hey all, added code snippet with the resulting outcome. Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: @JulienLachal it yields the same result. The bounds don't go outside the screen. I want to have a layout like the first image, I am getting a layout like second one.

Comment: Can you upload a ss or gif which provide in it your aim ?@RoyalGriffin

Comment: I've tried using `borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(500), topRight: Radius.circular(500))` on the `Container`. It works, but it's quite ugly, I haven't managed to have a "flatter" circle, no mater the radius. Have you tried a `CustomPaint`?

Answer (score 9):

I have managed to get similar to what I want by using scale transformation. Would like to see a different approach though.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  body: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.7,
      child: Container(
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have done this using clippath. If you change size of Container then Clippath size automatically change as per Container size.

You can modify Path for different shape as per your requirement so this is very useful.

Here, I just use ClipPath widget and I create MyCustomShape class for modify shape of child Container widget

```
 class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: ClipPath(
        clipper: MyCustomShape(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green[800],
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = new Path();  // use for shape your container
    path.lineTo(0.0, 100);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, 0.0, size.width, 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after reading your questions and comments many time i hope this what you are looking for

```
class dummy2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _dummy2State createState() => _dummy2State();
}

class _dummy2State extends State<dummy2> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animaton;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    animaton = Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 2.5).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));
    animaton.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.forward();
                    },
                    child: Text('forward')),
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.reverse();
                    },
                    child: Text('reverse'))
              ],
            ),
            body: Transform.scale(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple, shape: BoxShape.circle),
              ),
              scale: animaton.value,
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use SafeArea within a container to fill it. Like this:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: SafeArea(child: ### // you nav or functions),
),
```

See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Comment: Hey @r-flierman, this doesn't answer the question. Can you please provide an updated solution which is more relevant to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you could not reach the space in the outer corners. Missed the tiny green line in your screenshot so I figured you meant the rounded corners of the iPhone itself.